# How to allow TinyMCE 5 html, head and body tags?

Tags: tinymce-5

I'm using latest self hosted TinyMCE 5 editor.

I want to paste my own HTML into the editor and be able to edit everything including the html, head, body tags..

I've tried any combination of the following config, but TinyMCE keeps removing the html, head, body tags..

```
tinymce.init({
   selector                : '.editor,
   valid_elements          : '*[*]',
   valid_children          : "+html,+head,+body",
   extended_valid_elements : "html[*],head,body,script[*],style[*],link[*]",
   custom_elements         : "html,head,body,script,style,link"
});
```

How can I stop TinyMCE from removing them tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution while I was writing this post.

Simply add the 'fullpage' plugin to your config.

```
tinymce.init({
   selector  : '.editor,
   plugins   : 'fullpage',
});
```

Comment: 'fullpage' plugin is deprecated. is there any way to resolve?

Comment: I would also like to know. Seems to me there is no way to output a full HTML page now, and Gmail needs it to read the newsletter properly.